# Como enviar o id como parametro para url

Tags: javascript, api, url, fetch

Estou treinando a construção de um blog, ja consigo recuperar via API os posts e exibir na tela os resultados, porem preciso agora quando clicar no item (post), o id dele seja enviado para a url, formando do que pede na API pra exibição dos detalhes daquele item.

Está assim...

```js
    const areaPostagens = document.querySelector('.main');

    listagem().then((posts) => {  // Retorno do Fetch

       posts.forEach((post) => {

          areaPostagens.appendChild( exibePostagem(post) );

       })
    })

    exibePostagem = (post) => {
       console.log(post)

       const article = document.createElement('article');
       article.classList = 'post'

       const postagem = 
       `
          <a href="leitura.html/${post._id}" class="container-post">
             <h2 class="titulo">${post.titulo}</h2>
             <p class="paragrafo">${post.paragrafo.substr(0, 250)}...</p>
          </a>

          <footer class="rodape-post">
             <span>${post.data}</span>
          </footer>

          <hr>
       `
       article.innerHTML = postagem

       return article

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar assim:

```
...
const postUrl = `${window.location.pathname}/${post._id}`;

const postagem = 
       `
          <a href=${postUrl} class="container-post">
             <h2 class="titulo">${post.titulo}</h2>
...
```

Se não funcionar, explore outra propriedade do `window.location`.
Vale a leitura da API também, [veja aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/location).